# Custom bar component for a-frame

Tags: user-interface, three.js, aframe, virtual-reality

Do someone have thoughts of how to create component for a-frame, which will take input value and change itself level.

it should looks like this:

e.i. `<a-component level="50"></a-component>`

[image]

p.s. Maybe it is possible create two rectangles one with opacity above another, and the top one will simply animate it's height. But then the anchor should be set to the bottom side of the rectangle to scale only top side, not sure if a-frame support this.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as you suggest you can

1. create two rectangles (or cylinders) one with opacity above another
2. change the height of one
3. since by default the entity remains at its center you need to also offset its vertical position based on the height